# Unable to find /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin folder

Tags: asterisk

i have installed asterisk using the below link

http://draalin.com/installing-asterisk-in-ubuntu/

but failed to find "/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin" folder.i have searched a lot but could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards:

Desperate

Answer (score 1):

Folder `agi-bin` is in `/usr/share/asterisk` folder.